# jquery - ajax application - multiple hashes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, hash

So some web apps I've made have little "features" of ajax. Simple things usually, so I've only ever needed one hash (e.g. example.com/products#shirts). What if I wanted to have the "products" page loaded through ajax too? I know that it doesn't need to be in the hash, but for some functionality I prefer it (for user history and following urls and such).

Is there a plugin that somehow could handle making hashes and parsing them to get some name-value pairs or something? Or should I just do this myself?

So I could have something like (example.com/#products-shirts)

Not that I care how the properties are laid out in the url...

Suggestions?

Comment: Your question is kind-of hard to understand. Can you describe more clearly what it is you want to happen, to what, and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is [the jQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/), it's for *exactly* this (storage/history in the hash, including name/value pairs).